# How to "structure a web app" in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I'm starting to study Dart. It seems a nice language and in some aspects a real improvement over JavaScript. Since it claims to come with "batteries included" and to be meant for "structured web apps", though, I fail to understand how to actually structure a web app with it. Almost all the tutorials concentrate on language features, but Dart is quite simple and with many familiar bits, so that's the easy part.
Recently I fell in love with AngularJs. Now routing, two way binding, nested scope, clean separation of concerns... This actually means "structured" to me. But all the Dart examples I find are about selecting HTML elements and attaching listeners to them. This is old-style jQuery-like web programming and quite frankly the opposite of what I think of when I read "structured".
I don't want to compare a language and a framework and I know that Angular Dart is out, but I fear I'm missing something of vanilla Dart, because if it's all about a shorter syntax for lambdas, class based OOP vs prototypical OOP and the like, I don't  see how it's supposed to be a game changer: there are many other languages that provide an alternative JS syntax (à la CoffeeScript) and compile to it, and they don't come at the price of losing a perfect integration with existing JavaScript libraries and tools.

Sure, it has optional static typing, which may be great, but this comes more to a matter of preferences. I'm a full time Python and Ruby developer and I'm perfectly fine with dynamic languages. Is this what they mean by "structured"?

Thanks for any clarification that will eventually come.

Answer (score 7):

I work on AngularDart and have some experience structuring web apps.

When building a web app in Dart you would pick a web app framework, for example AngularDart or polymer.dart. Web app frameworks have a lot of opinion which is something that doesn't fit in the core libraries.  In that respect, "vanilla Dart" is fairly vanilla.

Since I'm most familiar with Angular, I'll discuss the Angular + Dart combination.  However, the rest of this post is also true for polymer.dart.

Angular provides a lot of structure to your app.  We've been able to provide a similar structure for both Dart and Javascript.  The concept of directives, data binding and dependency injection exist in both.

Dart provides more structure and we've been able to use that structure while building AngularDart.  e.g. the directive API is defined in terms of annotations which means that IDEs understand them and can help you code.

There are a number of "structure" features in Dart. One of my favourites is tooling. With types and annotations comes better tooling support.

Types in Dart are most useful when combined with tools.  Auto-complete is great but for large web projects, static analyze is even better.  For example, in AngularDart, since directives are annotated classes, we can assert that the annotation is correct.  Even more interesting is the potential to build tools.  In AngularDart, we have a tool that extracts and analyzes all directives.  This type of tooling is possible in Javascript but easy and supported by the language in Dart.

Answer (score 1):

- libraries, packages
- integrated dependency management with pub package manager
- class based instead of prototype based
- scopes of variables as one would expect in a modern language
- static syntax check
- better tooling support like code completion

Comment: In addition the Dart VM is faster than JavaScript, and also supports Snapshotting which greatly improves initial startup times and will be landing in Chrome (and hopefully other vendors in the future) and is already used for Dart serverside programming including dart2js, and pub.